# Specific sorting grouped items in collectionviewsource

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, grouping, collectionviewsource

I have a collectionviewsource of items. Each item is an object, which has a property SentTime and another property ParentId.
I want to group the items by their ParentId and to sort them in the following way:

- the items in a group should be sorted by SentTime ascending
- the groups should be sorted by SentTime descending

Here is a short example:

- Item 1 Sent 1/10, parent Id 1
- Item 2 Sent 2/10, parent id 1
- Item 3 Sent 3/10, parent id 3
- Item 4 Sent 4/10, parent id 3
- Item 5 Sent 5/10, parent id 1

Then the grouped list should look like this:

Item 3

- Item 4

Item 1

- Item 2
- Item 5

I have my collectionviewsource in the ViewModel.

```
this.MyCvs.SortDescriptions.Clear();
this.MyCvs.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SendTime", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
this.MyCvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ParentId"));
```

I know, that to order groups in CVS i just need to add another SortDescription by the property, by which the items are grouped (in my case ParentId) but it is not giving the result I want to obtain.
Thank all for help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

When you have grouping and sorting in a grid you have to set the sorting descriptions a bit differently than you did.

```
this.MyCvs.SortDescriptions.Clear();

this.MyCvs.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("ParentId"));

this.FilteredMessages.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ParentId", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
this.FilteredMessages.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SendTime", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

That is how you may achive that sorting shall only be applied per groups.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake: there is no other cvs (I mean FilteredMessages should be MyCvs). I tried your answer, and the items in the group are sorted OK, but the groups are not sorted in the descending order.

Comment: Because you set Ascending on ParentId it will sort ascending order. Set Descending and it will work other way. Btw, feel free to mark this answer or vote it up if it solved your problem.